# filtrar un valor especifico de un arreglo en JavaScript para asignarle una etiqueta p personalizada a cada valor del arreglo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Quiero filtrar un valor específico de un arreglo en JavaScript para asignarle una etiqueta p personalizada a cada valor del arreglo, tengo este código, pero simplemente se me recorre todos los valores que tengo almacenado en formularioName y se repite el botón.

Por ejemplo sí tengo en formularioName el valor de paco poder tener en Botón **to="/NombreAmenazaPaco"** y otro para Miguel **<Boton to="/NombreAmenazaMiguel"**, etc.

```
        {
        respuesta && respuesta.map (p =>  
        <p>{p.data().formularioName} <Boton to="/NombreAmenaza">Amenaza</Boton></p>)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si en p.data().formularioName viene el valor deseado suponiendo que sea algo así: "NombreAmenazaPaco" bastaría con usar backticks y concatener "/" + el valor recibido. (No es la única manera de concatenarlos).

**Así quedaría la concatenación:**

```
`/${p.data().formularioName}` //Como es JavaScript debes encerrar toda esa línea entre llaves { }.
```

**Así quedaría el código completo:**

```
  {respuesta &&
    respuesta.map((p) => (
      <p>
        {p.data().formularioName}
        <Boton to={`/${p.data().formularioName}`}>Amenaza</Boton>
      </p>
  ))}
```

El Botón podría ser un `<a>` donde el **href** sería lo mismo que el **to** que tienes en el `<Button>`.
Y en caso de estar usando react-router se podría utilizar `<Link to="concatenaciónAnterior">`.